# Android runtime exec stops if caller stops

Tags: java, android, shell, cmd, apk

I'm working with rooted android tablets and I want to execute shell command lines. However, I've seen they stop if the command launcher app stops. If there any way to keep the execution of the shell commands despite the originator app stops?

Thanks

This is exactly what I want to execute. I want to be able to update my app inside my app:

cmd I want to execute inside my App:

```
am force-stop myapp & install newVersionOfMyApp.apk & monkey -p myapp 1
```

Then when first part of the command is executed, rest is not executed. I've seen this can be solved in other OS by modifying the command (windows add a "cmd" and linux add "&" at the end). Does Android have any equivalent way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. You can do this by putting it after a nohup command:

```
nohup sh -c 'am force-stop myapp && install newVersionOfMyApp.apk && monkey -p myapp 1' &
```

EDITED with information of @syslogic

Comment: use either `&&` or `;` instead of `&` - then the commands will be processed sequentially (and no `at` is required, while not even knowing how long to wait). the `&` operator is only good to detach one single command (therefore I'd question that "solution").

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to detach the TTY from the console with an `&` (behind the command); while when the command has `exit 0` (success) or `exit 1` (error), the execution will halt nevertheless. running cron-jobs wouldn't require any console, at all. What I'm basically trying to tell is, that you probably should reconsider the way of how to put the commands there - while `adb shell` or cron does not require any GUI.

there also is `adb shell monkey` - while the MonkeyRunner might have (meanwhile) been replace with the UI Automator from the Support Library.

it's [Monkey](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkey.html) vs. [UI Automator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing.html).

I'd write it about like this, in `bash` - on a PC - with [ADB](http://adbshell.com/commands/adb-install):

`adb install -r com.acme.apk && adb shell monkey -p com.acme.AppName -v 500`

Comment: please, read edit of the question, I had made some clarifications. Thanks!

Comment: @jevora just found out, that the `-r` switch lets one replace an installed APK, while one can start monkey with adb, too ...it just requires an USB cable, but no shell terminal client on Android (therefore, there wouldn't be any interference either, when testing). I can see it's not exactly what you where asking for, but probably the most common way to do it.

Comment: That seems a nice solution when using the adb shell. However, when you are trying to execute the command line from inside an App (Using Runtime.exec) if you don't use "nohup" the command execution stops once I make the force-stop of the caller application. Basically what I managed to do thanks to nohup is to be able to update the same APP that is making the update. It's like when google play update itselfs, that it require rebooting after apk is installing (that's why I use force-stop and monkey after installing apk)